# Custom keyboard height is more than default keybaord

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, custom-keyboard

How to do the custom size of keyboard like what gBoard did in their keyboard (see the screenshot).
Here the search section is showing above the keyboard. I want to do the same in my application. Is anybody can help me to know which method is using to create such a view.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the `inputAccessoryView` property. Since it is a property on `UIResponder`, it is available on `UITextView`, `UITextField` and others. Assigning your custom view to `inputAccessoryView` will make it appear on top of the keyboard whenever the UI object you assigned it to has focus.

```
// Create your custom keyboard accessory view first
// then assign it
yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = yourCustomAccessoryView;

// Bring up keyboard and your accessory view
[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Read more here
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html

> **inputAccessoryView**
>   Assigning a view to this property causes that view to be displayed
>   above the standard system keyboard (or above the custom input view if
>   one is provided) when the text view becomes the first responder. For
>   example, you could use this property to attach a custom toolbar to the
>   keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But here, if click on the 'G' icon in the board, the search view showing above the default keyboard height. It seems the keyboard height increasing. Is it possible to increase the custom keyboard height ?

Comment: I have not tried it, but it sounds reasonable that you can change the height of the `inputAccessoryView` and possibly call `[inputAccessoryView setNeedsLayout]` to make its parent update its sizes.

Comment: I ment to write `[inputAccessoryView.superview setNeedsLayout]` above.